# What is the expression/word for "going against traffic (flow)"?

Tags: word-choice, words

Suppose you're driving in a one way street and see someone coming in the opposite direction.

What's the most natural way to say something like "Hey, you're going against traffic!"

I know how to say basically the same thing just re-wording a little:

> これは一方通行の道路だよ！　*This is a one way street!*

But I was wondering what's the word/expression to actually say "against traffic" (to go against traffic, or to go/drive in the wrong way, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 逆走する

is the most common expression for that. Often heard on the news. Because of the aging society, incidents of elderly people accidentally getting on highways in the wrong direction, going backwards on one way streets, and so on are increasing.

Comment: It was pretty simple then. Somehow could not find it immediately, maybe I should have searched better. Thanks!